# Detecting the first and last blank space in a string?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a minigame in Unity where the player is given several run-on sentences to correct. The player has to fix a run-on by using buttons provided on the screen to insert words and punctuations. Using the A and D or arrow keys to move, the player places an underscore (_) character at the next blank space from their current position, and the underscore acts as a cursor where words and punctuation will be inserted. This is done with a For Loop that breaks whenever the next blank space is found:

`ApplyStyling()` creates a red underscore at each space.

`RemoveStyling()` removes the red underscore at each space.

```
void Advance()
{
    //Find the next blank space.
    RemoveStyling ();

    for (int i = currentPosition; i <= sentence.text.Length; i++) 
    {
        //Make sure the user actually advances, and not stick to the same
        //blank space.
        if (sentence.text [i] == ' ' && i != currentPosition) 
        {

            currentPosition = i;
            ApplyStyling ();
            Debug.Log (currentPosition);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Retreat()
{
    RemoveStyling ();


    for (int i = currentPosition; i < sentence.text.Length && i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        //Make sure the user actually advances, and not stick to the same
        //blank space.

        if (sentence.text [i] == ' ' && i != currentPosition) 
        {

            currentPosition = i;
            ApplyStyling ();
            Debug.Log (currentPosition);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using For Loops because the positions of the blank spaces shift around whenever the player adds a word or punctuation.

The problem is, whenever the player Advances to the last blank space in the string, or Retreats to the first space, they're able to Advance or Retreat once more. This causes the underscore to disappear because of RemoveStyling activating by default. When the player comes back, the first or last space is skipped for next one.

How can I detect if the player is at the first or last space of a string to prevent them from Advancing or Retreating further than they need to?

Thanks.

Comment: Get the index of the current position in the string and compare to `string.IndexOf(" ")` to check the start and `string.LastIndexOf(" ")` to check the end.

Comment: an excellent answer by DGibbs